Should we make garden-of-eden a synonym of eden?
Currently garden-of-eden has 10 questions the earliest was Oct 2018.  But eden was in use for much longer (Sep 2011), has a tag description, and has 34 questions.
Should we make garden-of-eden a synonym of eden or retag those 10 questions?

I merged the eden tag into the garden-of-eden tag. I don't think it especially needs a description (which are generally recommended to be about usage, not simply what the topic is), but feel free to write one if you wish.

@curiousdannii Thanks.
